# Use AOP with APIs

Tags: java, hadoop, aop, spring-aop

I would like to use pointcuts of Aspects (Spring AOP) in Hadoop API. I don't want to modify the API, I just want to intercept the calls to the API methods. Is it possible with Spring AOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **The bad news:** No, it is not because Spring AOP is a proxy-based "AOP lite" framework which only works with Spring components. The syntax of Spring AOP is a subset of AspectJ, though.
- **The good news:** If you use full AspectJ instead of Spring AOP, you can do what you want, because AspectJ is independent of Spring and can be used with any Java class (even with classes produced by other JVM languages such as Groovy or Scala).